# Exclude custom slider from delaysContentTouches of scroll view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, touch, slideshow, hittest

Situation 1:
I've created a horizontal UIScrollView and added smaller horizontal UIScrollView as a subview.
It works fine - I can scroll both without any delay.

Situation 2:
I've created a horizontal UIScrollView and added my custom UIControl which works similar to "Slide to unlock slider". You can slide it horizontally.
However, when I touch my slider and move finger immediately, touches are passed to the ScrollView. When I touch slider, hold it for a while and then move it - touches are passed to the ScrollView.

Note that I don't want to set:

```
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO
```

I want scrollView to delaysContentTouches but excluding my slider.

I've tried to override hitTest:withEvent: in my slider's class. It returns "self" but it has no effect. Touches are stilled passed with the delay.